# body tag inside head tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a weird argument with a school teacher who says body tags go inside the `<head>` tag in HTML.

Now many students are learning it. Somehow, I can't find a way to prove him wrong. Yes, all the documentation including [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) show that `body` doesn't belong to `head` tag. I have tried writing some scratchpad codes with HTML + CSS + JS with `<body>` inside `<head>` and they worked just fine.

It's quite confusing that the browser's inspect element also didn't warn even after that CSS and JS code added.

Is there any obvious side effect or does something break when `<body>...</body>` is used inside `<head>...</head>`?

Comment: Tell him to run it through a HTML validator like https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and see what happens. If your teacher is arguing that this is an OK way to write HTML he shouldn't be teaching

Comment: Oh wow - this is a sad read. Posting my answer now - so many resources to prove this but the best bet is to just show him the HTML standard spec and HTML5 Recommendations. There's no argument against what the spec says and it spells this stuff out explicitly. There are also tons of use-cases for why it's spec'd this way...

Comment: Just answered with all the resources you need - please show your teacher the living HTML standard - they should be teaching it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58719528/11279581

Comment: The browsers don't warn about it because they simply fix it for you. In any case where an illegal element is used like this, the browser will simply close the elements as needed, so `<head><body></head>` becomes `<head></head><body>` and the second `</head>` is discarded.

Comment: @TylerH that is pretty interesting - I was just trying to break stuff by doing this and putting `<title>`, `<base>`, etc. at the bottom of the head, and putting the body inside head but above those. Per your comment, base and title end up and the bottom of the body instead, and head/body separated. And everything still works. So it really is like fool-proof at this point with modern browsers. Unfortunately it seems OP is not going to get the kind of proof they want (actually breaking).

Comment: Actually I am looking at the source code of Firefox 0.1 https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/0.10.1/  to see if I can break something or not! But at this point I really can't! I even tried to do that with one of my simple 2D game, that didn't break either!

Comment: @S.Goswami the only argument I can think of is that it's a risk that it won't work in browsers that have not implemented fixes for it like maybe some old browsers. And potentially newer or obscure browsers. So if you're making a website meant for a wide audience, why even take the risk? At this point, I'd say the burden of proof should be on your teacher - does he have any reasoning for why it should be nested, against all documents, specs, standards, etc.?!

Comment: @S.Goswami I might have something for you - it's a reach but makes some point that you just shouldn't mess with standards. I found innerHTML and textContent is not behaving consistently when you nest the body. Will update my answer to show...

Comment: Is your teacher's first name "Coach?"

Comment: Yeah, even the Firefox 0.1's HTML parser handles the opening and the closing head tags very well. Because HTML doesn't throw syntax errors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Debugging_HTML) in browsers, it won't show any error like a programming/scripting language. So it's hard to find something that "breaks" the page but validators show errors that are very helpful.

Comment: @S.Goswami I posted a break in my answer - it's a bit of a stretch but I think a valid case. innerHTML white space gets hosed up when you nest the body and textContent doesn't reflect what it should.

Comment: @MrRobboto At least it's *something*.

Comment: Here's a thought: try it in IE6.

Comment: Ugh, running GNU/Linux (no wine please!)

Comment: @3Dave yep, and in contrast to the absolutely non-existent case for why you **would** break standards. OP's teacher needs to just read this post at this point, how embarrassing.

Comment: Lol good point - tons of companies have basic tests to have you take or just search people's githubs, etc. If a hiring manager comes across stuff like this they very well may turn away - OPs teacher really is doing a lot worse than just asserting their weird web opinion.

Comment: Using MrRobboto's `document.all[0].innerHTML` shows what I really read in the source code - `// Make sure the head is closed by the time the body is opened.`, `CloseContainer(eHTMLTag_head, false);` file:  `mozilla-esr10/parser/htmlparser/src/CNavDTD.cpp` line no: 2490 assuming you have the source code from https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/0.10.1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the hard sources to prove this - the living HTML standard, and the HTML5 recommendation. These are the resources MDN uses but you're better off showing your teacher the original source that can't be disputed - this stuff was spec'd out from the beginning explicitly.

HTML Living Standard - Head:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element

HTML5 Recommendation - Head:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/document-metadata.html#the-head-element

HTML Living Standard - Body:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element

HTML5 Recommendation - Body:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/sections.html#the-body-element

It's spelled out...
Head:
"**Contexts in which this element can be used:
As the first element in an html element.**"

Body:
"**Contexts in which this element can be used:
As the second element in an html element.**"

And also the Content Model for `head` is totally different, explicitly stating `head` is for metadata, not flow content: 
"**Content model**:
If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no more than one is a base element.
Otherwise: **One or more elements of metadata content**, of which exactly one is a title element and no more than one is a base element."

EDIT: It's hard to show anything breaking because this is such an amateur and simple mistake, nearly every browser fixes it for you. That only applies to the DOM structure, properties, etc. though - as soon as you go to parse the innerHTML or textContent you see there are subtle differences in white space when you nest the body.

For instance, say you have an app that has an HTML editor that loads up the current page's HTML (for some reason) to show the user the document markup. If you nest the body, it will screw up white space and not reflect the actual source as it should. It's a stretch but this absolutely breaks the intended functionality of `innerHTML` and `textContent` IMO and would require workarounds in a use-case because the indentation and line breaks aren't preserved.

This is `innerHTML on a simple doc` - looks great, just like the code did:

[image]

Now if I nest the body, it does not look the same and is showing some mutated version after browser has messed with it to fix the invalid HTML - not to mention, it no longer reflects the structure that was in source - you will never see the browser allow the body inside the head:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, but I foresee a teacher saying "What's a standard and why should I care?"

Comment: I have almost no experience with school teachers, only older engineers so that whole concept is alien to me - how can a teacher in CS (especially web) not teach the value of web standards? Totally rhetorical, I only hear from others that it's become that bad in schools, sad to hear.

Comment: Schools are underfunded and don’t have staff with sufficient expertise for this kind of thing. For example, they’re teaching CS courses using Java - a language that inherently does its best to keep you away from learning how a computer actually works. It’s terrible. But, times being what they are, I do not find this sort of question surprising.

Answer (score 1):

You should share with them the standard HTML (root) tag documentation that will show HEAD and BODY as child elements. Reference: [The HTML Document / Root element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `<body>` tag are displayed in the browsers page, whereas the contents in `<head>` are not directly displayed. `<head>` should only contain the meta-data. In might work "just fine" because modern browsers are capable of handling bad code, but you may run into trouble with older (or other) browsers.

Also, it's just wrong and bad coding.

Comment: I have just tried the firefox version 10.0 https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/10.0.1/ which works fine...

Comment: It may look fine, but that does not mean it's correct. I am pretty sure you will run into problems sooner or later. Anyways, why not simply follow the standards as they were designed? There is no discussion about your teachers ideas, they are simply wrong.

Comment: That's true... That's not the norm to follow the rule, but I can't prove it to him and other students except using a validator - which is a good idea...

Comment: Show your teacher this paper (http://www.hjp.at/doc/rfc/rfc1866.html) written by the inventor of HTML. It clearly shows that the `<head>` comes (and must be closed) before the `<body>`  element.